# Python package IB installed but can not be imported

Tags: python

Can you guys please help me with one problem? I installed the package ib (Interactive Broker) for python https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ib using "pip install ib". It successfully install without error. However, when I try to import ib it says "No module named ib". I tried to download the source code and do python setup.py install, but also failed to import.

I tried to install other packages, and they work just fine.

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

P/S1.
Thank you very much for answering. I found out the cause. So instead of installing everything into a folder ib, so that I have:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ib/ext
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ib/opt

The installer somehow install the subfolder ext and opt directly to be two separate modules. So now I have:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ext
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opt

I can import ext and import opt. But now the problem is methods in ext and opt are calling each other by the name ib.ext.xxx. Does anyone know how to combine these two folders ext and opt together under the name ib and make python recognizing ib as an installed package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I was not able to get `pip install ib` to work either, for the reasons you mention in addition to it apparently not working with the latest versions of IB's API. Instead, I had to clone from https://github.com/blampe/IbPy

That version of ibpy works for me with the latest versions of the IB API (as of July 2014 anyway). I've been using it successfully for months now. All I had to do was clone ibpy somewhere, and install it from there:

```
git clone https://github.com/blampe/IbPy
cd IbPy
python setup.py install
```

See also: http://www.quantstart.com/articles/Using-Python-IBPy-and-the-Interactive-Brokers-API-to-Automate-Trades

Once you've got that installed, the interface in python is pretty much identical to the Java API interface: [IB API pdf](http://www.interactivebrokers.com/download/newMark/PDFs/APIprintable.pdf)

I found it useful to look at the TWS Test Client Java code included with the IB API.

Edit: IB now has their own native python API publicly available, so if you're just starting it would probably make more sense to use that. The interface is quite different from the ibpy Java wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check-

Make sure that the package is actually called ib.  Go to your python/Lib/site-packages directory and make sure that is what the folder is actually called.

Make sure you are using the same version of Python that you installed it to.  If you pip installed it in 3.3 and then tried to use it from 2.7, that would not work.  If you're not sure which Python you are using, follow your PATH variable from the front back- whichever comes first will run by default.